# Concat values on dataframe columns excluding NaN's

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, concatenation

I have a dataframe with n `store` columns, here I'm just showing the first 2:

```
     ref_id  store_0     store_1
0       100        c           b
1       300        d         NaN
```

I want a way to concat only the non-NaN values from `store` columns into a new column adding a comma between each value, and finally drop those columns. Desired output is:

```
     ref_id  stores  
0       100     c,b
1       300       d
```

Right now I've tried `df['stores'] = df['store_0'] + ',' + df['store_1']` with this result:

```
     ref_id  store_0  store_1  stores    
0       100        c        b     c,b
1       300        d      NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
cols = df.filter(like='store_').columns

df2 = (df
 .drop(columns=cols)
 .assign(stores=df[cols].agg(lambda s: s.dropna()
                                        .str.cat(sep=','), 
                             axis=1))
 )
```

Or, for in place modification:

```
cols = df.filter(like='store_').columns

df['stores'] = df[cols].agg(lambda s: s.dropna().str.cat(sep=','), axis=1)
df.drop(columns=cols, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
   ref_id stores
0     100    c,b
1     300      d
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```py
df_ = df.filter(like='store')
df = (df.assign(store=df_.apply(lambda row : row.str.cat(sep=','), axis=1))
      .drop(df_.columns, axis=1))
```

```
print(df)

   ref_id store
0     100   c,b
1     300     d
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
df['store'] = df.filter(like = 'store').apply(lambda x : ','.join(x[x==x]),1)
df
Out[60]: 
   ref_id store_0 store_1 store
0     100       c       b   c,b
1     300       d     NaN     d
```